# How to build a where clause for table B using rows from table A

Tags: python, sql

Table A = Rules Table:

```
RuleID | Rulecase | CDE | CDE_VALUE
(RL123 , 1, 'CU_GFC_ID', '11A')
(RL123, 2, 'GFCID', '10')
(RL123, 1, 'GFCID', '11')
(RL123, 1, 'CLU', 'IS NULL')
```

Table B = Product_Table

```
Select * 
from Product_table 
where CU_GFC_ID in ('11A') 
  and GFCID in ('11') 
  and CLU IS NULL;
```

Trying to create a script with functions in which I can pass RuleID as a parameter to extract the rows and build a where clause which I can concatenate to the second SQL query as mentioned above. Any suggestions if this is possible?

Comment: Please include sample data for the second table and also the final expected result.

Comment: Not enough information in the question. Not clear what is expected here.

If you just want to be able to lookup the product_table with the RuleID through code then just join your Rules table and add a where clause in code containing your parameter.

Comment: Dispite low information, if I get what you want, I would try by getting the DISTINCT VALUES of 'CDE' and store them in some List or DataTable (tabCDEs), then for each entry in tabCDEs, I create another List or DataTable (tabCDEValues) concatenating CDU_VALUE with some char as separator. Finally, loop in tabCDEs and for each CDE, loop inside tabCDEValues for the current CDE and then it, use some string builder to arranje your sql command.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback. I think Ricardo almost got my requirement. I will upload some sample data to explain it little better. @ Ricardo, can you please let me know how can I store the extracted data in List of Datatable?